# Unable to get current location currency localIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

> Using iOS Swift, Xcode 7.1, iOS 9

I want to show app users current location currency symbol in my product cost.

I am using the following code:

```
let price = 20.00
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() 
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(price)!) // $20.00
```

But I am getting the currency in $. As I am using the device in India, shouldn't NSLocale.currentLocale give me the currency in rupee?

I also tried the following in playground

```
let currency = String(NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier) // "en_US"
```

But this also shows me US identifier.

So can anyone tell me how I can get currency symbol based on users current location?

Answer (score 1):

NSLocale is based on your device settings

> Settings -> General -> Language Region

In your case you have to use iOS specific corelocation to get the users current location and then determine the currency based on that.

Comment: Thanks. So can you suggest how I can get currency based on users current location?